# Struts2 Jquery Ajax form serialize

Tags: struts2

I am learning Struts2 and have the following question on submitting a form with Jquery serialize. I have an action class where I have an object called Policy and the policy class has set of fields as shown below. With jquery ajax I want to set a json string  in my Action class and would like to deserialize it to an object.

How much ever I try, I am not able to set the string I defined in my action class. Below is the code

```csharp
Class CassPolicy{
  String policyNumber;
  String name; 
  //getsets for members

}
```

Action:

```csharp
Class PolicyAction{
   String cassPolicyString;
   CassPolicy cassPolicy = new CassPolicy();
   //getsets for members

   String save(){
//In save method  I want to convert the policyString to policy object
//policyString always returns null
   } 
}
```

JSP:

```js
$.ajax({
 url:PolicyAction.action,
 type:'post',
 data:$("#policyForm").serialize(),
 async:true,
 success:function(data){
 }

});

<s:form id="policyForm">
    <s:textfield name="cassPolicy.policyNumber" label="policyNumber"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="cassPolicy.name" label="name"></s:textfield> 
</s:form>
```

I even tried in ajax something like `data:{cassPolicyString:$("#policyForm).serialize()}`

Can someone help me point to the right direction or what is the right way to achieve my task?

Comment: Your form field names don't match the action property names, nor is it clear if there are actually getters/setters for the properties. Are you using the JSON plugin? What's going out on the wire?

Comment: Thanks Dave for replying.. I do have getters and setters in my object and my Action class.. I am using Struts2-Json plugin and have json-default in my struts.xml... I see the values in my json request from browser as cassPolicy.policyNumber=12345&cassPolicy.name=Test

Comment: Your form field names don't match the action property names.

Comment: Change `cassPolicy.policyNumber` to `policy.number` and `cassPolicy.name` to `policy.name`. That's it...

Comment: In parameters mapping, fantasy is not allowed :D

Comment: Thanks Andrea and Dave..I changed the code to above and still my values are not getting set.

Comment: Please don't hide the code, if they could see the getters/setters they would know if they were correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally.. The issue is form serialize does not give a json format. I used the code in below link to serialize my form as json object and added a interceptor ref element to my action in struts.xml which finally assigned my form values to cassPolicy object.

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

Comment: Hey can you please paste your interceptor code, how are really converting json data to CassPolicy Obj. I am also struggling for same requirement from long time. Tx In Advance.